# Custom marker InfoWindow in google maps iOS swift?

Tags: swift, storyboard, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, infowindow

I'm using google map iOS in my app , i want to show custom marker info window.How can i create it?
I'm using storyboards and swift as the language.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem with this guy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223716/ios-google-maps-api-markerinfowindow-vs-markerinfocontents Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5):

I had one such problem with my app.

1. In your ViewController.swift:

   ```
    class ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
           func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

                   let placeMarker = marker as! PlaceMarker

                   if let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView {
                       infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.place.name

                       if let photo = placeMarker.place.photo {
                           infoView.placePhoto.image = photo
                       } else {
                           infoView.placePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "generic")
                       }

                       return infoView
                   } else {
                       return nil
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

2.Then create a UIView class:

```
import UIKit

class MarkerInfoView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var placePhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

3. Then create a xib file named the same as UIView class:

[image: Like this]

Note that the class name is the same as UIView class. You can add label and images as per your requirement. Connect those IBOutlets to the UIView class as shown.

Hope this helps you. All the Best!

Comment: How can i add gesture to this View of XIB file?

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate for your `GMSMapView` and implement this function in your delegate:

> func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
>   }

You can create the view programmatically inside this function, or through a nib file.

**UPDATE**

Do not forget to change the marker's infoWindowAnchor:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#a6668957ca7b6857355ee6cd9ab944a92

Comment: but how can i make it custom like shown in the image.

Comment: You create it like you create any normal UIView, either in a Nib file, either programmatically inside the function. No magic here.

Comment: I am trying to create programatically like this, using a WKWebView, and it does not work, it only loads a blank view. It will start showing the html of the webview if I enable `tracksInfoWindowChanges`, but then the cpu gets stuck at full usage. What else can be missing?