# iOS: Google Maps API - markerInfoWindow vs markerInfoContents

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I looked through the [Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ada45fe7f5b0e7c3b21047b9d09138dce) and the description does not seem to help much.

I'm following an old [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) that made use of `markerInfoContents` however, when I used the delegate it didn't return what I expected.

With `markerInfoContents`: My custom view seems to override the default view

[image]

When I used `markerInfoWindow`, the results were what I expected:

[image]

I am simply pulling in a custom UIView from a xib file like so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let placeMarker = marker as! PlaceMarker
    print(placeMarker.name)

    if let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName(name: "MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView {
        infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.name

        return infoView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

(Replace `markerInfoWindow` with `markerInfoContents` for the first image results)

With `markerInfoContents` it created the anchor and the shadow effect of the box. When using `markerInfoWindow` it does not create that anchor or shadow effect like in the tutorial.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi Simon, please mark the answer if it solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation link posted, when using `markerInfoContents`: "If this method returns a view, it will be placed within the default info window frame.", so your view is constrained within the default window (that's why it shows the anchor and shadow). It looks like the default infowindow is smaller than the UIView form your xib, so it truncates it.

The use of `markerInfoWindow` shows the view you pass directly, so if it does not have the anchor or shadow, it will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the default shadow effect and the anchor with `markerInfoContents` then you have to do it like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
{
    let placeMarker = marker as! PlaceMarker
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
    if let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName(name: "MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView 
    {
        infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.name
        view.addSubview(infoView!)
        return view
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```